# Rendering an animation as image sequence only renders the first image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, image-sequence

I have set the settings to render my animation as an image sequence, Sequencer is activated in the post-processing area as seen in the picture below.
However, when I want to render it and go to render animation, and not render image, it always just renders the first frame and stops there...
Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix this? To render all the frames as PNGs?

Here is the blend file:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @RobinBetts _Compositing_ and _Sequencer_ are usually both enabled by default. It does not matter if there is nothing in the sequencer pipeline, in this case it will simply render the compositor output/render layers.

Comment: Turn the Compression right down to 0% on the Output format panel. (I think the default is 15%.) You have it set to 100% at the moment which is drastically slowing down the render output!

Comment: i am not sure whether this is the reason or whether you have an add-on installed or it might be the OS - but if i open your file, the denoiser setting is empty: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qe28.png if i choose a denoiser, the rendering works for me

Comment: @JohnEason Thank you, that fixed the problem! I have set it to 100 first because I want to have absolutely perfect renders without compression loss of quality.

Comment: @Chris I have chosen OptiX for the denoiser, I got a RTX 3060 12GB VRAM that works well with the OptiX denoiser. Which Denoiser did you choose?

Comment: i am on a mac and the only choice i had was openimagedenoiser

Comment: @user140193 With a 4kx4k file, each png is over 130Meg uncompressed, so it's not surprising that it takes for ever to compress each frame 100%, even with just a plane in the scene.  Turn it down to the default 15% and each frame is then just under 20Meg when saved and renders and saves quickly.

Comment: Also worth reading the answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/what-does-the-compression-setting-do-to-a-png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that helped thanks to @JohnEason is to reduce the compression to 0 or just 15 percent.